# Using template on a QWidget constructor

Tags: c++, qt, templates

I have created a QWidget class that should take a template pointer as an input. Doing so with a method works fine, however when I try to use it on the QWidget's constructor I get an error. Here's the code:

```
#ifndef GADGET_H
#define GADGET_H

#include <QObject>


struct P2D {
    Q_GADGET
    Q_PROPERTY(P2D p2d READ getP2D )
    Q_PROPERTY(float m_x READ getX WRITE setX)
    Q_PROPERTY(float m_y READ getY WRITE setY)

    P2D getP2D() {return *this;}
    float getX() {return this->m_x;}
    void setX(float x) {this->m_x = x;}
    float getY() {return this->m_y;}
    void setY(float y) {this->m_y = y;}

public:
    float m_x;
    float m_y;
}; Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(P2D)

#endif
```

Main:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "gadget.h"

#include <QApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QMetaObject>
#include <QMetaProperty>
#include <QVariant>
#include <QWidget>
#include "objectintrospector.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    qRegisterMetaType<P2D>();
    P2D point;
    point.m_x = 10;
    point.m_y = 25;

    objectIntrospector *oi = new objectIntrospector(nullptr, "P2D", &point);
    oi->show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

QWidget:

```
#ifndef OBJECTINTROSPECTOR_H
#define OBJECTINTROSPECTOR_H

#include <QWidget>

class objectIntrospector : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    template <class T>objectIntrospector(QWidget *parent = nullptr, const char* typeName =  nullptr, T *ptr = nullptr);
    ~objectIntrospector();

private:
    Ui::objectIntrospector *ui;
};
```

I get the following error:

```
undefined reference to `objectIntrospector::objectIntrospector<P2D>(QWidget*, char const*, P2D*)'
```

Is there any way to solve this error? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Did you implement this function in your .cpp file?

Comment: @JarMan I haven't. But the thing is, I'm using templates because the constructor should take a generic Q_GAGDET as input, so I can't implement this specific function objectIntrospector::objectIntrospector<P2D>(QWidget*, char const*, P2D*) because it could be anything on P2D's place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From comments:

> Did you implement this function in your .cpp file?
>
> I haven't. But...

Hmm... you should know that the only way to get rid of the issues is defining the functions body.

So, if you need it to be generic, define the body in the header as well (and the compiler will handle the rest); Something like:

```cpp
template <class T>
objectIntrospector::objectIntrospector(QWidget *parent, const char* typeName, T *ptr)
{
    // Your logic here...
}
```

Comment: Once that is fixed `Q_OBJECT` should cause you new issues (unless your Qt version, or meta-object-compiler now supports templates, of course)

Comment: I did some template members for QObjects... As long as they aren't involved in signal/slot or property handling, it should be fine

Comment: It is working now, I am just trying to find a way to make it look cleaner (with no success though)